# Instantiate subclass from mother class intelligently

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, inheritance, initialization

Let's say I have a motheclass (abstract or not) **Item** and two subclasses **ItemA** et **ItemB** which both inherit from **Item**

All instances are created based on a NSDictionary through the following method

```
-(id)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)d{

//first instantiate common properties from the motherclass
    if ([super initWithJSON:d]){
        //Do specific stuff for the subclass
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now let's say I fetch from a webservice an array that can contain both ItemA & Item to be created.

Currently what I do is that use a if/then condition to determine which subclass I will instantiate based on the dictionary content, for instance :

```
 [(NSArray*)data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            if ([obj[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"A"])
                [interactions addObject:[[ItemA alloc] initWithJSON:obj]];
            else if ([obj[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"B"])
                [interactions addObject:[[ItemB alloc] initWithJSON:obj]];
            else
            [interactions addObject:[[Item alloc] initWithJSON:obj]];

        }];
```

Now my point is the following : is there a way to have only one line of code that will - by default - instantiate an **Item** object, and based on the kind an **ItemA** or an **ItemB**
In other words, can I write some code in the init method of the motherclass **Item** to instantiate a subclass instead if some conditions are fulfilled in the NSDictionary parameters which is parsed ?

Thanks

Comment: A and B are always Item, so simply caat it and ignore if they are A or B.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I don't get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your mother class, add a convenience method like this:

```
 +(instancetype)itemWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)obj {
        id item; 

        if ([obj[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
            item = [[ItemA alloc] initWithJSON:obj];
        } else if ([obj[@"kind"] isEqualToString:@"B"]) { 
            item = [[ItemB alloc] initWithJSON:obj];
        } else {
            item = [[Item alloc] initWithJSON:obj];
        }

        return item;
 }
```

then use it like this:

```
 [(NSArray*)data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     [interactions addObject:[Item itemWithJSON:obj]];
 }];
```

Comment: that encapsulates the logic what Item type to init / or even HOW to init it, inside that convenience function!

Comment: Seems like the good and proper way to do it, thank you. Thought about it, but mainly wanted to check if there was other best practices.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [NSClassFromString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSClassFromString) .

Example pseudo-code:

```
NSString *className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Item%@", obj[@"kind]];
Class metaClass = NSClassFromString(className);

*instance = [[metaClass alloc] initWithJSON:obj];
```

You then encapsulate this behavior in a static [class factory method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassFactoryMethods/ClassFactoryMethods.html) to your mother class. See Daij-Djan's answer for details.

Comment: Thanks, I already did that in the past, which works and is really convenient. This time the naming convention of the different subclasses is not that close the one of the mother class, which would imply to add if/then logic.
Still thanks for underlying that  !